# Displaying JSON List in honeycomb layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to display a JSON list in honeycomb. The thing is, I have a fragment and cannot change the class to extend to ListActivity or Listfragment. However, if someone could instruct me where to start(is this a new class I need or is there a simple way to display JSON on the layout)?

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /*
     * (new Thread(new Runnable() {
     * 
     * @Override public void run() { fetchPage(); } })).start();
     */

    List<JSONObject> testing = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();



    (new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            List<JSONObject> test123 = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
            RssReader reader = new RssReader();
            test123 = reader.getLatestRssFeed();
            Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = test123.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());

            }
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    })).start();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.newspaper_fragment, container, false);
}
}
```

And here is the layout I have so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/wallpaper">

<!-- List view -->


</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.